# JavaFX: Unknown property in css file

Tags: java, css, eclipse, javafx, properties

I have a css file that I'm trying to import in SceneBulider . The file contains the following text:

```
.pagination .pagination-control { visibility: hidden; }
```

The problem here is that the property *visibility* is unknown (to quote the warning, Unknown property: "visibility"). Does visibility really doesn't exist, or is it an error from eclipse ( I am using eclipse neon, with SceneBuilder and e(fx)clipse installed). What I am trying to do is hide the pagination labels by using a css file, since I couldn't find another method.

Thank you.

Comment: using `.setStyle("visibility: hidden;");` works just fine for me, what are you trying to use it on?

Comment: Thank you so much :D.  It finally fixed the problem of hiding my pagination labels of a table.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS (JavaFX) all properties start with the keyword "-fx-" (excepted fo [Visibility](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)), So either the syntax is false or this property does not work with this selector !

Comment: I changed my code in .pagination .pagination-control { -fx-visibility: hidden; }, and now -fx-visibility is unknown

Comment: I checked and the property visibility exists without keyword -fx-